# How to add an f-String to a URL? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What exactly am I doing wrong? I figured if I did a browser.get(), it'd know that whatever is entered into the Browser entry box, it'd enter into the URL.

How does it actually work?

```
def openSite():
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
new = 1


browser = Entry(width=15)
browser.pack()
_boxNo_ = browser.get()

url = f'https://www.google.com/{_boxNo_}'


Submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=openSite)
Submit.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `browser.get()` inside the function. Right now, as soon as `entry` is created, you are fetching the values. So, it is always blank because your fetching the results like after 1 ms, well before the user even has a chance to enter the url, and `webbrowser` doesn't open the link.

Here is how the code should look like.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
root=Tk()
def openSite():
    _boxNo_ = browser.get()
    url = f'https://www.google.com/{_boxNo_}'
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)

new = 1

browser = Entry(width=15)
browser.pack()

Submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=openSite)
Submit.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh, needs tobe within the 'def'.

Gotcha. Makes sense. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Dexsana, no problem